# Execution problem with secondary user on nexus 7 2013

Tags: multi-user

I have created 2 more users on my Nexus 2013.
The problem with these 2 non-administrator users is, I can not run a lot of apps which work fine on admin user (ex ilmeteo.it - "Baby bus" children games......).

These applications start and close automatically with the report "....the applicationname closed unexpectedly..."

How can give the correct permissions on the secondary users to excute all the applications?

Answer (score 0):

If you can add an app to a restricted profile, but it won't work in a restricted profile, that's a bug in the app. Only the developer of the app can fix it: you should report the problem to them through their official support channel so that they can fix it.